# Java WebClient post request with different body and response JSON

Tags: java, spring-boot, post, spring-webclient

I am trying to create a POST request with the Spring Boot Webclient library. However, the input body is different from the response, and the response doesn't contain an error.

```java
private Mono<ApplicationView> createMarketplaceApp(boolean published, String name, Type type) {
    WebClient webClient = WebClient.create("url");
    AppCreationRequest appCreationRequest =
            new AppCreationRequest(published, name, type);
    Mono<ApplicationView> newApp = webClient
            .post()
            .uri("/api/v1/apps")
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .header("X-Auth-Token", "xxx-yyy-zzz")
            .body(Mono.just(appCreationRequest), AppCreationRequest.class)
            .exchangeToMono(response -> {
                if (response.statusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)) {
                    return response.bodyToMono(ApplicationView.class);
                } else {
                    // Turn to error
                    return response.createException().flatMap(Mono::error);
                }
            });
    return newApp;
}
```

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@QueryEntity
@Document
public class ApplicationView {
    private String id;
    private String type;
    private String displayName;    
    private Boolean everPublished;
    private Boolean publicDisabled;
    private List<String> workIn;
    private Map<String, Object> ext;
}
```

```java
@Data
public class AppCreationRequest {
    @NotNull
    private Boolean published;

    @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    private Type type;
}
```

Not sure why it doesn't step on the line

```java
if (response.statusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)) {
```

What should I expect in the newApp return object?